# Show that $B_j$ is a Cauchy sequence with respect to the operator norm

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, matrices, normed-spaces, cauchy-sequences

Given $A\in L(\mathbb R^n)$ such that $||A||<1$, set $B_j=\sum\limits_{r=0}^n A^r$.

Show that $B_j$ is a Cauchy sequence with respect to the operator norm.

$||B_m-B_n||=||\sum\limits_{r=0}^m A^r-\sum\limits_{r=0}^n A^r||=||\sum\limits_{r=n+1}^m A^r||\leq\sum\limits_{r=n+1}^m ||A^r||<m-n$

Not sure where to go from here, is this right so far?

EDIT:

$\sum\limits_{r=n+1}^m ||A^r||\leq\sum\limits_{r=n+1}^m ||A||^r=\sum\limits_{r=0}^m ||A||^r-\sum\limits_{r=0}^n ||A||^r=\frac{||A||^{n+1}-||A||^{m+1}}{1-||A||}$

Still can't see where this is going.

Comment: I assume you meant $B_n$ not $B_j$. Here's a trick you need: $\|A^k\| \le \|A\|^k$, so you get part of a geometric series in your final sum.

Comment: Is that inequality intuitive? Don’t really understand the operator norm.

Comment: How have you defined your operator norm?

Comment: Yes: $||AB||\leq ||A||\cdot||B||$ is fairly clear, since $||AB||=\sup_{||x||\leq 1} ||AB(x)||=\sup_{0<||x||\leq 1, B(x)\neq 0} ||B(x)||\cdot ||A (\frac{B(x)}{||B(x)||})|| \leq \sup_{0<||x||\leq 1} ||B(x)|| \cdot \sup_{0<||y||\leq 1} ||A(y)||=||A||\cdot||B||$

Comment: where we've used that $B(x)/||B(x)||$ has norm $1$ whenever $B(x)$ is non-zero.

Comment: I calculated the geometric series as $\frac{||A||^{n+1}-||A||^{m+1}}{1-||A||}$? Think I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write $m = n + p$ with $p \geq 1$. Then your right-hand side becomes
$$
||A||^{n+1} \frac{1 - ||A||^{p}}{1 - ||A||}
$$
and
$$
0 \leq \frac{1 - ||A||^{p}}{1 - ||A||} \leq \frac{1}{1 - ||A||}
$$
Now set $n$ large enough to bound the right-hand side with a variable $\varepsilon$.